# default value : where are they stored on the Database Odoo?

Tags: odoo, default-value

where the default value are stored in Odoo?  
for example the supplier tax on the product `product_supplier_taxes_rel`

Comment: Can u provide more details which default value are u talking about?

Comment: any default value on the field defined earlier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ir.values** :

Holds internal **model-specific action bindings** and **user-defined default** 
field values. definitions. This is a legacy internal model, mixing 
two different concepts, and will likely be updated or replaced in a 
future version by cleaner, separate models. You should not depend 
explicitly on it.

For more information [refer this](http://useopenerp.com/v8/model/ir-values?t=bbr&r=mthmvip&d=1&uui=1445254257)

Go to

**Setttings => Actions => User-defined defaults**

[image]